# How to count and sum a group of rows that share the same first letter

Tags: php, mysql, count, group-by, substring

i have data like:

```
    studyID | participantID | question | problems 
       1    |      1        |   A100   |     3    
       1    |      1        |   A200   |     2    
       1    |      1        |   A300   |     4   
       1    |      1        |   B100   |     2   
       1    |      1        |   B200   |     5  
       1    |      2        |   A100   |     3    
       1    |      2        |   A200   |     3    
       1    |      2        |   A300   |     3   
       1    |      2        |   B100   |     1   
       1    |      2        |   B200   |     6
```

and i want output like:

```
    section | num questions| total problems | average problems 
       A    |       3      |       18       |        6         
       B    |       2      |       14       |        7
```

The code that would go in sql fiddle is given below:

```
    SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
    SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
    SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

    CREATE SCHEMA `interviewcodes` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
    USE `interviewcodes` ;

    CREATE TABLE `interviewerlkup` (
      `InterviewerID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      PRIMARY KEY (`InterviewerID`))
    ENGINE = InnoDB
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

    CREATE TABLE `studylkup` (
      `StudyID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      PRIMARY KEY (`StudyID`))
    ENGINE = InnoDB
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

    CREATE TABLE `studyinterviewers` (
      `StudyID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
      `InterviewerID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`StudyID`, `InterviewerID`),
      INDEX `fk_StudyInterviewers_InterviewerLkup1_idx` (`InterviewerID` ASC),
      CONSTRAINT `fk_StudyInterviewers_InterviewerLkup1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`InterviewerID`)
        REFERENCES `interviewcodes`.`interviewerlkup` (`InterviewerID`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_StudyInterviewers_StudyLkup1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`StudyID`)
        REFERENCES `interviewcodes`.`studylkup` (`StudyID`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

    CREATE TABLE `participant` (
      `ParticipantID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `ParticipantCaseID` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `StudyID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
      `InterviewerID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`ParticipantID`),
      INDEX `fk_participant_studyinterviewers1_idx` (`InterviewerID` ASC),
      CONSTRAINT `fk_participant_studyinterviewers1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`InterviewerID`)
        REFERENCES `interviewcodes`.`studyinterviewers` (`InterviewerID`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_participant_studylkup1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`StudyID`)
        REFERENCES `interviewcodes`.`studylkup` (`StudyID`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

    CREATE TABLE `coderlkup` (
      `CoderID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      PRIMARY KEY (`CoderID`))
    ENGINE = InnoDB
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

    CREATE TABLE `studycoders` (
      `StudyID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
      `CoderID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`StudyID`, `CoderID`),
      INDEX `fk_StudyCoders_CoderLkup1_idx` (`CoderID` ASC),
      CONSTRAINT `fk_StudyCoders_CoderLkup1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`CoderID`)
        REFERENCES `interviewcodes`.`coderlkup` (`CoderID`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_StudyCoders_StudyLkup1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`StudyID`)
        REFERENCES `interviewcodes`.`studylkup` (`StudyID`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

    CREATE TABLE `studyquestion` (
      `StudyQuestionLabel` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `StudyID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`StudyQuestionLabel`, `StudyID`),
      CONSTRAINT `fk_StudyQuestion_StudyLkup`
        FOREIGN KEY (`StudyID`)
        REFERENCES `interviewcodes`.`studylkup` (`StudyID`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

    CREATE TABLE `codedata` (
      `StudyID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
      `ParticipantID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
      `CoderID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
      `StudyQuestionLabel` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `TotalScore` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT 0,
      INDEX `fk_CodeData_Participant1_idx` (`ParticipantID` ASC),
      INDEX `fk_CodeData_StudyCoders1_idx` (`CoderID` ASC),
      INDEX `fk_codedata_studyquestion1_idx` (`StudyQuestionLabel` ASC),
      PRIMARY KEY (`StudyID`, `ParticipantID`, `CoderID`, `StudyQuestionLabel`),
      CONSTRAINT `fk_CodeData_Participant1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`ParticipantID`)
        REFERENCES `interviewcodes`.`participant` (`ParticipantID`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_CodeData_StudyCoders1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`CoderID`)
        REFERENCES `interviewcodes`.`studycoders` (`CoderID`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_codedata_studylkup1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`StudyID`)
        REFERENCES `interviewcodes`.`studylkup` (`StudyID`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_codedata_studyquestion1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`StudyQuestionLabel`)
        REFERENCES `interviewcodes`.`studyquestion` (`StudyQuestionLabel`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

    SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
    SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
    SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;

    INSERT INTO `studylkup` (`StudyID`) VALUES ('3');

    INSERT INTO `interviewerlkup` (`InterviewerID`) VALUES ('1');
    INSERT INTO `interviewerlkup` (`InterviewerID`) VALUES ('2');

    INSERT INTO `coderlkup` (`CoderID`) VALUES ('1');
    INSERT INTO `coderlkup` (`CoderID`) VALUES ('2');


    INSERT INTO `studyinterviewers` (`StudyID`, `InterviewerID`) VALUES ('3', '2');
    INSERT INTO `studyinterviewers` (`StudyID`, `InterviewerID`) VALUES ('3', '1');


    INSERT INTO `studycoders` (`StudyID`, `CoderID`) VALUES ('3', '2');
    INSERT INTO `studycoders` (`StudyID`, `CoderID`) VALUES ('3', '1');

    INSERT INTO `participant` (`ParticipantID`, `ParticipantCaseID`, `StudyID`, `InterviewerID`) VALUES ('1', 'AJW123', '3', '2');
    INSERT INTO `participant` (`ParticipantID`, `ParticipantCaseID`, `StudyID`, `InterviewerID`) VALUES ('3', 'AJW125', '3', '1');

    INSERT INTO `studyquestion` (`StudyQuestionLabel`, `StudyID`) VALUES ('A100', '3');
    INSERT INTO `studyquestion` (`StudyQuestionLabel`, `StudyID`) VALUES ('A200', '3');
    INSERT INTO `studyquestion` (`StudyQuestionLabel`, `StudyID`) VALUES ('A300', '3');
    INSERT INTO `studyquestion` (`StudyQuestionLabel`, `StudyID`) VALUES ('B100', '3');
    INSERT INTO `studyquestion` (`StudyQuestionLabel`, `StudyID`) VALUES ('B200', '3');


    INSERT INTO `codedata` (`StudyID`, `ParticipantID`, `CoderID`, `StudyQuestionLabel`, `TotalScore`) VALUES ('3', '1', '1', 'A100', '3');
    INSERT INTO `codedata` (`StudyID`, `ParticipantID`, `CoderID`, `StudyQuestionLabel`, `TotalScore`) VALUES ('3', '1', '1', 'A200', '3');
    INSERT INTO `codedata` (`StudyID`, `ParticipantID`, `CoderID`, `StudyQuestionLabel`, `TotalScore`) VALUES ('3', '1', '1', 'A300', '3');
    INSERT INTO `codedata` (`StudyID`, `ParticipantID`, `CoderID`, `StudyQuestionLabel`, `TotalScore`) VALUES ('3', '1', '1', 'B100', '3');
    INSERT INTO `codedata` (`StudyID`, `ParticipantID`, `CoderID`, `StudyQuestionLabel`, `TotalScore`) VALUES ('3', '1', '1', 'B200', '3');
    INSERT INTO `codedata` (`StudyID`, `ParticipantID`, `CoderID`, `StudyQuestionLabel`, `TotalScore`) VALUES ('3', '3', '2', 'A100', '3');
    INSERT INTO `codedata` (`StudyID`, `ParticipantID`, `CoderID`, `StudyQuestionLabel`, `TotalScore`) VALUES ('3', '3', '2', 'A200', '3');
    INSERT INTO `codedata` (`StudyID`, `ParticipantID`, `CoderID`, `StudyQuestionLabel`, `TotalScore`) VALUES ('3', '3', '2', 'A300', '3');
    INSERT INTO `codedata` (`StudyID`, `ParticipantID`, `CoderID`, `StudyQuestionLabel`, `TotalScore`) VALUES ('3', '3', '2', 'B100', '3');
    INSERT INTO `codedata` (`StudyID`, `ParticipantID`, `CoderID`, `StudyQuestionLabel`, `TotalScore`) VALUES ('3', '3', '2', 'B200', '3');
```

***UPDATE***

i have tried:

```
        print("<table  align = 'center' border = '2'>");
        print("<tr>");
            print("<td align = 'center'>Section</td>");
            print("<td align = 'center'>Total Number of Items</td>");
            print("<td align = 'center'>Total Number of Problems</td>");
            print("<td align = 'center'>Average Number of Problems</td>");
        print("</tr>");

        $sql1 = "SELECT LEFT(codedata.StudyQuestionLabel, 1) as Section,
                    COUNT(*) as NumQuestions,
                    SUM(codedata.TotalScore) as TotalProblems,
                    AVG(codedata.TotalScore) as AvgProblems
                FROM interviewcodes.codedata codedata
                WHERE (codedata.StudyID = ".$StudyID.")
                GROUP BY LEFT(codedata.StudyQuestionLabel, 1)
                ORDER BY LEFT(codedata.StudyQuestionLabel, 1) ASC;";

        // run query and get result set      
        $rs1 = $conn->query($sql1);

        // check if query1 is wrong;
        if ($rs1 == false)
        {
            $errmsg = "Wrong SQL1: ".$sql1."Error: ".$conn->error;
            trigger_error($errmsg, E_USER_ERROR);
        }
        else
        {
            while ($arr1 = $rs1->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
            {
                print_r($arr1);
                print("<tr>");
                    print("<td align = 'center'>".$arr1['Section']."</td>");
                    print("<td align = 'center'>".$arr1['NumQuestions']."</td>");
                    print("<td align = 'center'>".$arr1['TotalProblems']."</td>");
                    print("<td align = 'center'>".$arr1['AvgProblems']."</td>");
                 print("</tr>");
            }
        }
        print('</table>');
```

i changed the above code a little bit and got the following output.

```
    section | num questions| total problems | average problems 
       A    |       6      |       18       |        3         
       B    |       4      |       14       |       3.5
```

i want this instead:

```
    section | num questions| total problems | average problems 
       A    |       3      |       18       |        6         
       B    |       2      |       14       |        7
```

it seems to be counting every record with a question that starts w/ the letter A when what i really want is for it to count the distinct questions that start with the letter A.  how do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL, `substr()` starts counting at 1 and not 0.  In any case, you can use the `left()` function and not have to worry about that:

```
SELECT LEFT(Question, 1) as section, COUNT(*) as numQuestions, SUM(Problems) as totalProblems 
FROM codedata 
WHERE (StudyID = ".$StudyID.") 
GROUP BY LEFT(Question, 1);
```

You can also add the ration, which you also seem to want, or use the `avg()` function:

```
SELECT LEFT(Question, 1) as section, COUNT(*) as numQuestions, SUM(Problems) as totalProblems,
       AVG(Problems) as averageProblems
FROM codedata 
WHERE (StudyID = ".$StudyID.") 
GROUP BY LEFT(Question, 1);
```

Comment: i tried your code and have modified the above question with your suggestion.  however, i am not getting any output or error messages.  even print_r does not yield anything.  could you please check my code above and let me know what is wrong?

Comment: @ajwong4 . . . The SQL looks reasonable.  It is possible the semicolon is throwing things off.

Comment: removed the semicolon and still didn't get any output.  it's strange that the sql is correct (doesn't throw an exception) and yet when i do a print_r there is nothing in the array.

Comment: @ajwong4 . . . That would suggest that nothing matches the `where` clause.

Comment: i added the schema for the codedata table.  shouldn't my where clause work?

Comment: i have data for the correct studyID, coderID, studyQuestionLabel, and totalScore.  what could be preventing the where clause from finding the correct data?

Comment: @ajwong4 . . . Can you load the data on sQL Fiddle?

Comment: i tried to input a chopped down version but this is the error i get:  Schema Creation Failed: Access denied for user 'user_2_5a6df'@'%' to database 'interviewcodes':  i have pasted the schema and data in the above question in case you have better luck inputting it into sql fiddle

Comment: i changed my query a little bit and now i'm getting output.  however, it is not quite what i wanted.  i would like it to count the distinct questions that begin w the letter A, not each record whose question begins with the letter A.

Comment: @ajwong4 . . . Then change `count(*)` to `count(distinct question)` or something like that.